# I got error while installing Django on pycharm

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip

I am getting the following error while trying to install `Django` for `python3`

> (base) C:\ShashiPractice ProjectStudent>pip install django
>   Collecting django
>    Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
>   (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>  
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...
>   y failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)')))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

You made a small mistake.
The pip command is as follows:
`pip install Django`

Note that the the D in Django is in block letter. Hope this solves your problem :)